# Querying with custom columns along with normal columns on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my example data frame and

> > > df

```
index,Customer_MailID,Event_Quantity,Amount_Final,Channel,Week_Name,Venue_Name,Event_Genre1
1,aa@hotmail.com,2,172,Web,MON-TO-THU,Tivoli Cinema: Extreem,COMEDY
2,bb@gmail.com,2,234,Web,MON-TO-THU,CineMAX: Pacific Mall Subhash Nagar,ACTION
3,cc@yahoo.com,3,502,Mobile,MON-TO-THU,DT City Centre: Shalimar Bagh,ACTION
4,dr.d@gmail.com,4,1402,Web,Sunday,Rajiv Gandhi Cricket Stadium: Hyderabad,SPORTS
5,dd@hotmail.com,4,6449,Web,Saturday,Subrata Roy Sahara Stadium: Gahunje,SPORTS
6,deep.d@gmail.com2,1,82,Mobile,MON-TO-THU,Tivoli Cinema: Hyderabad,ACTION
7,r@yahoo.co.in,1,219,Web,MON-TO-THU,INOX:JP Nagar -Central Mantri Junction,ACTION
8,nnd@gmail.com,2,384,Web,MON-TO-THU,Wave: City Emporium Mall,ACTION
9,v90@gmail.com,4,1402,Web,Sunday,Rajiv Gandhi Cricket Stadium: Hyderabad,SPORTS
```

i want to execute following kind of query on it..

select the set of columns of data frame (or) all columns of the dataframe where, 
((Sum(Amount) >=1000)) && (Event_Quantity <5)) and so on.. adding n number of conditions mixed up with & and | condition.
The problem here we are facing is there is no such column called (sum(Amount)) on the original data frame.In such scenarios 
is there any generic solution available for querying pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, data every Customer_MailID is used only once. I presume in the real data there are multiples which would make sum(Amount_Final) != Amount_Final. If that presumption is correct, then one solution is to create a column to carry the sum of Amount_Final and then use that in your subset.

Something like this:

```
totalAmount = pd.DataFrame( df.groupby('Customer_MailID')['Amount_Final'].sum()).reset_index()
totalAmount.columns = ['Customer_MailID', 'Total_Amount_Final']
df = df.merge(totalAmount)
```

At that point you'll have a new column called Total_Amount_Final you can use in your subset like this:

```
df[(df.Total_Amount_Final > 1000) & (df.Event_Quantity <5)]
```

Comment: Dear JD, I dont want to create the custom column in the dataframe gain.I want to apply the where condition for the custome column

Comment: how do you propose applying a where condition to a field without calculating the field?